# Fire event after jQuery select list options have changed via another elements onchange event

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a select list (#select2) whose options are changed each time another select list(#select1) is changed.

select2's options are always dependent on #select1's value and are changed each time #select1 is changed.

Is there a function I can bind to the #select2 element that will fire after its option list changes are complete (each time its affected by #select1)?

I cannot seem to add an onchange handler to the select1 element to do what I want because it appers to fire before select2's options list is complete.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `trigger()` and `bind()` methods to raise and listen for custom events:

Try this:

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
    // update options in #select2
    $("#select2").trigger("updatecomplete");
});

$("#select2").bind("updatecomplete", function() {
    // this will fire when #select1 change event has finished updating the options.
});
```

More info on [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

---

**UPDATED ANSWER - Sept 2016**

Note that `bind()` is now deprecated. You should use `on()` instead:

```
$("#select2").on("updatecomplete", function() {
    // this will fire when #select1 change event has finished updating the options.
});
```

Comment: Excellent! can be treated as "click out" event

Answer (score -1):

Changes made through javascript do not fire events.  You will need to fire it yourself in the code which changes it.

```
$("#select2").change();
```

Comment: Just to be clear, should the $("#select2").change() event not fire as a result of the select1's jquery which resets the options in select2?

Comment: Right, I'm assuming you've already bound a handler to `select2`, but this event will not fire automatically.  You can call `change` yourself to fire the event.